# The user name is stored in an a connected object

Tags: grails, spring-security

I'm using grails and I have the following domain classes:

```
class User {

    transient springSecurityService

    String password
    static belongsTo = [person: Person]
 }
```

And

```
class Person {
    String name
    String emailAddress
     ....
}
```

I would like to use the person object's email address as the username in Spring Security.

According to the Spring Security manual, that just takes setting the property of `grails.plugins.springsecurity.userLookup.usernamePropertyName` to the non-"username" field.

I've tried person.emailAddress, and that doesn't work.

How can I get Spring security to use the Person reference to the User? I can't put the password on the Person class, and I've tried to use inheritance (that brings up other issues).

---

So I've traced this down to [GormUserDetailsService](https://github.com/grails-plugins/grails-spring-security-core/blob/master/src/groovy/grails/plugin/springsecurity/userdetails/GormUserDetailsService.groovy), where this is being called and implimented. The code that is used to find the user is:

```
    def user = User.findWhere((conf.userLookup.usernamePropertyName): username)
    if (!user) {
        log.warn "User not found: $username"
```

How would I structure the userNamePropertyName so that I could get it look through the child property?

Comment: Actual code would help over bullet points

Comment: Can you post the Person and User domain classes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's bad idea. Just replace email to User, but if you want to use this field in person, create link to this field.

```
   class User {

        transient springSecurityService

        String password
        String email
        static belongsTo = [person: Person]
     }
```

and Person:

```
    class Person {
        String name
        String emailAddress
         ....
        String getEmail(){
         user.email //if relations OneToOne 
        }
        static hasOne = [user:User] //if relations OneToOne 
    }
```

You should stay relations OneToOne, because I can't imaginate in what case it should be OneToMany

UPD. Or you can try try this one:
class User extends Person{..}
and in spring security config write just email, but i'm not sure.